# W3 Total Cache plugin integration

Tags: cache

I am working on a plugin (widget) that is using some transients that are updated from time to time.

That said, when these transients are updated, I think I will need to flush the cache to display the new data properly.

Thus, I wonder if have some way to flush the cache only for widget instead of entire cache. Do you guys have some advice?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to flush the specific cache you can do that: the plugin has functions for that

```
<?php
flush_pgcache();  // Page cache
flush_dbcache();  // Database cache
flush_minify();  // Minify cache
flush_all(); // All caches
?>
```

and you just need to call it like this:

```
<?php 
$w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all();
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. However I was not planning to flush entire cache. I wonder if is possible to flush just the widget area. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: There was no option/function available to flush widget cache. You have to `flush_pgcache();` or `flush_dbcache();` based your needs.

Comment: Hey, looks like it is possible to do what I need using Fragment Caching :) Thanks for the help!